# HTML: regex expression to match multiple examples

Tags: html, regex

I have an HTML text, where I want to find images and videos. Found some examples, but can't make it work.

I have working example for only images:

```
MatchCollection urls = Regex.Matches(this.item.text, "<img.+?src=[\\\"'](.+?)[\\\"'].*?> );
```

For both i want to make something like this:

```
MatchCollection urls = Regex.Matches(this.item.text, "<img.+?src=[\\\"'](.+?)[\\\"'].*?> | <iframe .*?/> | <iframe .*?</iframe>");
```

The last regex found 0 images, where first got 3.

Comment: Use an HtmlAgilityPack to parse HTML in C#. Regex is not the best tool for this.

Comment: Will check it, thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/777850

Comment: @giorgio Yes! Exactly, what a gem.

Comment: I'll repeat the standard response that should be given *every time a question like this is posted*: **Do not use Regex to match HTML**. Use an HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
(<img.+?src=[\\\"'](.+?)[\\\"'].*?>)|((<iframe.*?\/>)|(<iframe.*?<\/iframe>))
```

You were missing the parenthesis.

Comment: MatchCollection urls = Regex.Matches(this.item.text, "(<img.+?src=[\\\"'](.+?)[\\\"'].*?>) | ((<iframe .*?/>) | (<iframe .*?</iframe>))");

not working